# Using Gtk.spinner with a long time function

Tags: python, gtk, pygobject

I am trying to get working a gtk.spinner using Pygobject in python. The main thing is that I use this element to show the user that a long time action is in progress. The problem is that the spinner stops when doing the function.

the code is here:

```
.....
def create_image(self,spinner):
    ....
    spinner.start()
    # Heavy function
    spinner.stop()
.....
```

And this doesn't works. I would accept some help, thanks!

Comment: can you show me your code to better understand the usage of the spinner, please? BTW, I haven't been able to comment below your last comment...?! :-/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your heavy function needs to occasionally let the GUI process accumulated events. For example, you can occasionally run:

```
while gtk.events_pending():
    gtk.main_iteration()
```

Another option is for the heavy function to run in a separate thread, leaving the main thread to process the events and spin the spinner. In that case, you will need to redesign your `create_image` function to be asynchronous. For example:

```
def create_image(self, spinner, finishcb):
    spinner.start()

    def thread_run():
        # call heavy here
        heavy_ret = heavy()
        gobject.idle_add(cleanup, heavy_ret)

    def cleanup(heavy_ret):
        spinner.stop()
        t.join()
        finishcb(heavy_ret)

    # start "heavy" in a separate thread and immediately
    # return to mainloop
    t = threading.Thread(thread_run)
    t.start()
```

Now, instead of calling `create_image`, you need to pass it a callback that will be called when the image is ready. I.e., instead of:

```
image = self.create_image(spinner)
```

you write:

```
self.create_image(spinner, self.store_created_image)
```

Comment: Should I use this inside the heavy function?

Comment: @fernandezr Yes, if you can. The downside is that it might also enable other interaction with the GUI, and fire timer events, but that's the easiest way to spin the spinner during a large calculation.

Comment: I've now added an alternative approach that fires off a new thread to calculate the image.